# Fastest way to take difference of elements in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table, difference

Using the following dataset, what is the fastest way to compute for each ID (Col1) the difference with all the other ID02 (Col2) within the same time (Col3, `t`) without using `dplyr`, (`data.table` welcome!)?

More specifically, for each ID in column `ID`, I would like to take all possible differences between its relative value in the column `value`, and the value in the column `value` relative to the other observations with the same `ID` number (within the same year). That is, I want a data frame with all differences across pairs (`ID`-`ID2`) with the same `ID` and same `t`.

The dummy dataset is:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(rep(c(1,2,3,4),3),2), ID2 = rep(c(rep(5,4), rep(6,4), 
                 rep(7,4)),2), t = c(rep(1,12), rep(2,12)), value = runif(12) )


   ID ID2 t     value
1   1   5 1 0.6991799
2   2   5 1 0.0879940
3   3   5 1 0.5876535
4   4   5 1 0.2105821
5   1   6 1 0.9483806
6   2   6 1 0.5076218
7   3   6 1 0.1790157
8   4   6 1 0.5229501
9   1   7 1 0.7365285
10  2   7 1 0.5298920
11  3   7 1 0.6172215
12  4   7 1 0.3365588
13  1   1 2 0.6991799
14  2   5 2 0.0879940
15  3   5 2 0.5876535
16  4   5 2 0.2105821
17  1   6 2 0.9483806
18  2   6 2 0.5076218
19  3   6 2 0.1790157
20  4   6 2 0.5229501
21  1   7 2 0.7365285
22  2   7 2 0.5298920
23  3   7 2 0.6172215
24  4   7 2 0.3365588
```

The difference should be taken over the column `value`. Then the new data.frame should be created like this, where `1(5)` in the first row refers to the row with `ID = 1` and `ID2 = 5` in year `t = 1`.

```
   ID    ID2 t     value
1   1(5)   6 1     0.6991799 - 0.9483806
2   1(5)   7 1     0.6991799 - 0.7365285
3   1(6)   7 1     0.9483806 - 0.7365285
4   2(5)   6 1     0.0879940 - 0.5076218
2   2(5)   7 1     0.0879940 - 0.5298920
3   2(6)   7 1     0.5076218 - 0.5298920
...
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample expected output? Easier than deciphering your explanation of the operation.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you want to calculate the difference in value across distinct ID/ID2 pairs across t? How do you want to treat duplicate `ID`s within the `t`-group? See rows 1, 5 and 9 for example.. They have the same ID value.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation: I rewrote the question and added an example. Thank you!

Comment: Always `set.seed` for random data like `runif`. Otherwise, we cannot reproduce your sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty quick. I'll leave any formatting and dropping of columns you don't want to you:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkey(df, ID, t)

# self join on the keys (ID and t)
# then keep only rows where ID2 is less than the joined ID2
result = df[df, allow.cartesian = TRUE][ID2 < i.ID2]
# calculate the difference
result[, diff := value - i.value]
result
#     ID ID2 t     value i.ID2    i.value        diff
#  1:  1   5 1 0.2468819     6 0.34515017 -0.09826830
#  2:  1   5 1 0.2468819     7 0.01068400  0.23619786
#  3:  1   6 1 0.3451502     7 0.01068400  0.33446616
#  4:  1   5 2 0.2468819     6 0.34515017 -0.09826830
#  5:  1   5 2 0.2468819     7 0.01068400  0.23619786
#  6:  1   6 2 0.3451502     7 0.01068400  0.33446616
#  7:  2   5 1 0.1749664     6 0.29682198 -0.12185559
#  8:  2   5 1 0.1749664     7 0.40023788 -0.22527149
#  9:  2   6 1 0.2968220     7 0.40023788 -0.10341590
# 10:  2   5 2 0.1749664     6 0.29682198 -0.12185559
# 11:  2   5 2 0.1749664     7 0.40023788 -0.22527149
# ...
```

Comment: Another similar option within 1 `[]` is `setorder(
    DT[DT, on=.(id, t, id2<id2), allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=0L,
        .(ID=x.ID, x.ID2, ID2=i.ID2, t, value=x.value-i.value)],
    t, ID, ID2)[]`

Comment: Ha! I started with a non-equi self-join like that, but I had `id2 != id2`, which isn't allowed. Then I changed to this approach before I realized that the `<` was more appropriate, and forgot I could go back to the non-equi join. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you both! this really helped! sorry for the delay to accept the answer!